# Reverse tunnelling to expose jupyter port via EC2

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-ec2, jupyter

I want to expose a local Jupyter Notebook by using EC2 as a proxy. Ideally I'd like to access the jupyter notebook on my local machine, by connecting to the EC2's exposed port, done by visiting `{EC2 Public IP}:11111/notebook`.

I'd figured it would be identical to reverse tunneling a local port to my EC2 server's port, then exposing the EC2 port via security groups, but it doesn't seem to work - I get "This site can’t be reached" when visiting the above URL.

What I have set up right now:

Local Machine:

`jupyter notebook --port 11111 --ip=0.0.0.0`

`ssh -f -N -R11111:localhost:11111 ubuntu@{EC2 Public IP}` [reverse tunnel EC2's 11111 to local machine's 11111]

EC2:

Expose port `11111` ([EC2 Security group Inbound Rules entry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjz7u.png))

Are there any steps in the process I'm missing out on?

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: You may have to specify the interface on the local side, i.e. `-Rlocalhost:11111:localhost:11111`.